# How can I structure MYSQL DB talk to not have redundancy

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables `users`, `userchoices`, and `choices`

Users

- userId
- name

UserChoices

- userId
- choice1
- choice2
- choice3

Choices

- choices
- pic_loc

I am trying to link these three tables to each other. I thought about adding a `choiceId` to table `Choices` and then getting rid of the fields `choice1`... in `UserChoices` but that would cause one user to have multiple records. Is there a way that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User table:

- UserId
- Name

Choices table:

- ChoiceId
- pic_loc

UserChoices table:

- UserId
- ChoiceId

UserChoices table would be used to map both User and Choices tables

Comment: wait as i look at this, wouldnt this create redundancy in the userchoice? Say there is more than one choice a user can select then you'd have a multiple rows for each user @Sonikas

Comment: if you have predefined choices and users, only proper way to assign choices for user is though mapping table, yes it would duplicate user ids but it no problem, to prevent user to select same choice twice you can add unique constrains. Mapping table is such situation is best practice.